# Seamless Remote Windows on Linux Client

Tags: rdp, remoteapp

I really like the RemoteApp features of Windows Server 2008
Are there any solutions for similar functionality for *Linux* clients and a Windows server?

We have users that are running Linux on the desktop and rdesktop to a Windows server, mostly for Outlook. It would be nice if Outlook could behave more seamlessly.

From what I can tell rdesktop doesn't do that yet, it only implements RDP 5.  I've also seen ["SeamlessRDP" from Cendio](http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/), which is an extension to rdesktop, but I can't get it to work. I think it doesn't work in Vista, but that is just a guess.

Any ideas? And thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I emailed Cendio and they confirmed SeamlessRDP doesn't work with Server 2008 for unknown reasons. It appears there is no way to do this with a 2k8 server. It's either windows clients with RemoteApp or using a pre-Vista OS with seamlessrdp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SeamlessRDP is a great solution - I set it up so that internal IIS admins had a linux box that they could get to remote server IIS snap-ins without having full-fledged Windows administrator desktop/filesystem/etc. access.  Keep playing with it - it's worth it.

Comment: Was this on Server 2k3?

Answer (score 2):

The [FreeRDP project](http://www.freerdp.com/) is also working to get rdp 6/7 remoteapp capabilities implemented.

SeamlessRDP does work well enough now to use this way but its not really utilizing the microsoft remoteapp feature in Windows Server 2008

I also liked using the app called Remmina. Although they don't have support for RemoteApp yet they will when FreeRDP has it ready. Remmina also does some other cool things like map your linux Home Directory onto Windows so you can save files there with the Windows app. Ditto for the default Linux Printer... where the Windows app can print to any printer the Linux system has installed.

Answer (score 2):

RemoteApp support was implemented in FreeRDP 1.0. See their [wiki](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/RemoteApp) for instructions. I successfully tested it with 1.0.1 against a Windows 7 terminal server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work on Server 2008.  The server must have Terminal Services role, Terminal Services remote gateway installed, and the applications that you want to access with seamless rdp must be made available in Terminal Services Remote Access.  The windows that get created leave a little to be desired, and I am still working on trying to get the applications to not disappear if accidently minimized.